# Make IntelliJ IDEA stop over writing project code style settings

Tags: intellij-idea

Case: I am working in a large shared project with version controlled code styles defined in `.idea/codeStyles/Project.xml` and I have noticed that whenever I save a file in IntelliJ, some of these rules are removed.

I do not know where the changes that are being applied are coming from and I do not understand how to make this stop.

As things stand, I cannot easily create PRs that have unacceptable side effects when using this IDE.

How do I stop this behaviour?

Comment: Could you please clarify which file do you save? Do you edit project.xml manually? Which rules are removed?

Comment: No matter what file I save, project.xml gets updated. I was not even aware of the existence of that file before I saw my PR in GitHub. All the rules for one particular language, Kotlin, get removed.

Comment: Do you have Settings Sync (`Settings | Settings Sync`) turned on?

Comment: Settings sync is disabled.

Comment: Is it reproducible with other projects? For investigation we'll need before/after state of the file and screenshot from IDE settings with the mentioned rule. For further investigation please report issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA attaching requested data

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is due to a bug in 2024.1.x versions of IntelliJ.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-348081/2024.1-keeps-deleting-project-settings-if-these-settings-are-using-the-default-value